# Ember cli, how to initialize a service with a controller?

Tags: ember.js, ember-cli

I have a service,  called clock

```
//app/services/clock.js

export default Ember.Object.extend({
    pulse: Ember.computed.oneWay('_seconds').readOnly(),
    tick: function () {
      var clock = this;
      Ember.run.later(function () {
        var seconds = clock.get('_seconds');
        if (typeof seconds === 'number') {
          clock.set('_seconds', seconds + (1/4));
        }
      }, 250);
    }.observes('_seconds').on('init'),
    _seconds: 0
});
```

I also have an initialzer where I want to register the **clock** service and then inject it into my "interval" route/controller.

```
// app/initializers/clock-service.js

import ClockService from 'app/services/clock'; 

export default {
        name: 'ClockServiceInitializer', 
        initialize: function(container, application) {
          container.register('clock:service', ClockService);
          app.inject('controller:interval', 'clock', 'clock:service');
  }
};
```

Edit: it appears to be this:

```
export default {
  name: 'services',
  initialize: function(container, app) {
    // Inject into all routes and controllers

    // Or if you wanted, into a specific route
    app.inject('controller:index', 'clock', 'service:clock');
  }
};
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have basically the same thing, though I inject into all controllers.

In the initializer:

```
//container.typeInjection('component', 'store', 'store:main');
application.register('clock:service', ClockService, { singleton: true });
application.inject('controller', 'clock', 'clock:service');
```

And in the controller, using it like:

```
updateView: {
  // ...
}.observes('clock.pulse')
```

Comment: Thanks! Mine seemed to work without having "register" at all..what is the difference between register and inject?

Comment: @redconservatory I had to look it up here: http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Application.html but register appears to register your factory as available for dependency injection while inject actually injects your object into the factory you specify (controller, route, etc.)

Comment: the files in the question are named according to the ember-cli standard. so it should work even without registering, because the resolver will do that automatically :-)